# Hive regex rlike error in parenthesis

Tags: regex, hive

I am trying to search for a keyword followed by a (. The query is of the form:

```
select * from <tablename> where colname rlike 'somename\(';
```

Since ( is a metacharacter, I escaped it. However hive throws an error while processing the above regex related to unclosed groups. How do i match a '(' in hive regex?

Comment: Double escape the `(`: `select * from <tablename> where colname like 'somename\\(';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either double the `\`:

```
select * from <tablename> where colname RLIKE 'somename\\(';
                                        ^^^^^          ^^
```

Or use it in a character class:

```
select * from <tablename> where colname RLIKE 'somename[(]';
                                        ^^^^^          ^^^
```

Otherwise, the `\(` is parsed as a literal `(`, and is considered an opening group regex operator requiring the closing `)` counterpart.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried the double \ approach but I still get the same error - "java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index ..."

My query looks like this at the terminal:
$hive -e "select col1, col2 from tblname.dbname where col3 rlike 'somename\\\('"

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use `RLIKE`?

Comment: sorry, typo. it is rlike.

Comment: Hive is using Java regex flavor and regex patterns are to be defined the same way. This should work.

Comment: the second suggestion of using the character class works. Thanks.